# W3c Markup Validator on Windows 2003 with Apache

Tags: windows-server-2003, apache-http-server, w3c-markup-validator

OS = Windows 2003 (latest sp / hotfixes etc)
Perl = Active Perl 5.8.9 Build 825
Apache 2.2.11

Followed the following How-To:
http://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html

Facing the following errors : (had an html error too, but I used Perl Package manager to upgrade the required package. Now, the Package manager isn't showing any update of the following package and some others too :

SGML::Parser::OpenSP version 0.991 required--this is only version 0.99 at C:/www/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 61.

Q : How can I download the latest package for OpenSP ?
Q : Would It be just a matter of click and install the package?

If someone can provide a step by step that would be very helpful, I am not fluent with building perl packages.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like it'd be a lot less effort to install Firefox and the Webdeveloper toolbar (which uses the validator service from w3c rather than trying to work it out locally - note that it can submit entire pages rather than just URLs so you can still use it for development work not available on the internet - but you need to be connected to the internet to post the code.

Comment: Thanks Symcbean for your suggestion, we already have it and use it, we still need the local copy and we already have the version before the latest one working. I have installed the latest one too but i am unable to find the perl packages required in order for this to work without errors. for e.g. SGML::Parser::OpenSP version 0.991, If I comment it out or change the version number to .99 in the "check" file, it works but it's not the latest one then.